# Play framework 1.2.5 crud search can not search on integer fields

Tags: playframework, crud

I'm using crud module in Play framework 1.2.5. I learned how to customize blank, show views, but I have problem with crud search. When I input string into search field, I get results including that string, but when I input an integer (for example, 5) it returns nothing. What's interesting, if some string field contains 5, that is returned, but integer field isn't?